# Need advice on underlayment for finished / converted garage floor

Tags: concrete, basement, framing, vinyl-flooring

We recently bought a split level ranch in New England that we are renovating to make safe for our family.  The previous owner had vinyl tiles in a converted garage, that is about halfway under grade in the back.  We have removed the previous finishing and would like to frame out and finish the garage so as to have extra space.  The problem is, we are unclear of what to do to make a) the framing safe from water and b) the flooring safe from water.  The garage floor is dry, but it's obvious that at some point the previous tiles had expanded a bit due to moisture.

The current options are using something like Dricore or DMX 1-Step over the bare floor and installing vinyl plank on top of it, or installing vinyl plank straight over the floor. Also, we have considered painting the room with Drilok to waterproof it before installing the framing and the floor, but I have heard conflicting reports on whether this should be done.  The issues at hand are:

1. How can we avoid creeping moisture and possible upwelling being transferred to the sheetrock and frame? There is some evidence of mold from previous finishing that we are abating.  Should we install the framing directly on the concrete, over the floor or leave an air gap in some way?
2. What is the most effective long-term subfloor solution for this case?  Is Drylok appropriate, or something more breathable?  It's not exactly a basement but the rear end of the room is under grade by 2-3 feet while the front part is at grade (see pictures).  The outside is tarred but we were thinking of excavating and or grading around the outside to possibly correct any problems.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't think vinyl tiles would expand due to moisture.

Comment: I think it was more that the moisture got to the adhesive underneath the vinyl tiles and made them easier to pull up.